# Android sdk manager On ubuntu

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, ubuntu, adt

I download ADT  from this link http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030.zip
then installed it and when run eclipse/Android sdk Manager, a process doing on it but later I getting a message :

```
Failed to run the Android sdk manager.check the android Console view for details.
```

On Windows in sdk folder , a .exe file is available for run Android SDK manager but for Ubuntu is not Available.

Comment: Have you checked your console for error ?

Comment: No . how I check it ??

Answer (score 2):

Download Android SDK manager for Linux. Install ddms plugin to your eclipse. Map your Android SDK platform-tools(adb) to your Android properties[ Click on Window preferences and choose Android].